# nginx location overwrites alias

Tags: nginx, alias

I have an alias "/temp" that works ok, but when I add another location block, the alias returns 404.

Working config: `http://mysite.com/temp/blank.gif -> OK`

```
server {
    # ...
    location /temp {
        alias  /var/www/temp;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Error config: `http://mysite.com/temp/blank.gif -> 404`

```
server {
    # ...
    location /temp {
        alias  /var/www/temp;
    }
    location ~ \.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {
        expires  30d;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Here is my full config: http://pastebin.com/yExq0nMY

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested `location` for this.

nginx matches only one `location` block at the `server` level, so you have to nest them in this circumstance. For full details, see the official documentation: [How nginx processes a request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

```
server {
    # ...
    location /temp {
        alias  /var/www/temp;
        location ~ /temp/\.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {
            expires  30d;
        }
    }
    location ~ \.(?:jpg|png|gif)$ {
        expires  30d;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the resource on how nginx processes these locations/request. I like include other static files simple example that `location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|bmp|html|htm)$ {  # headers, etc }` and you could do this for PHP or CFML with something like this that matches your dynamic files `location ~ \.(cfm|cfml|cfc|jsp|cfr)(.*)$ { include tomcat_proxy_params; } `

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a root directory set? Please post more of the config.

Some essential reading as well: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Comment: Yes I have. Here is my full config: http://pastebin.com/yExq0nMY